# Is it bad to use registered IP ports?

Tags: networking, ip, ports

Is it very bad form or very inadvisable to use IP ports registered with IANA?

[Their site says](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt):

> Assigned ports both System and User ports SHOULD NOT be used without
>   or prior to IANA registration.

Do people tend to follow this rule?

Comment: You just run the risk of breaking something else that relies on that port (either as a service or as a client).  It only matters if that risk comes to fruition.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you are using port number 21 on your program (my_prog.bin) then FTP service will be affected because the port number 21 is binded to your application (my_prog.bin).

In order to resolve this issue better make use of port number more than reserve port.

More over reserve port can be binded only by process / daemon running as root.

For in-house products you can use reserve ports (Not good thou) but if you are planning to make your application public then you have no other choice other than following IANA registration.